# error CS0246: The type or namespace name `AForge' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aforge, n-queens, genetic

I'm trying to make a n-Queens with Genetic Algorithm in Unity3D, but this error appears everytime...

code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

using AForge.Genetic;
using AForge.Math;

namespace AlgoritmoGenetico
{
public class GA : MonoBehaviour {

    int populationSizeBox;
    int iterationsBox;
    int nRainhasBox;
    int crossoverRateBox;
    int motacaoRateBox;
    int paradaBox;
    //int selecao;

    private String log = "";
    private int nRainhas = 14;
    private int nPopulacao = 14;
    private int nGeracoes = 8000;
    private int nParada = 100;
    private double crossoverRate = 0.75;
    private double mutationRate = 0.01;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Iniciar ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void Iniciar(){
        configuraAlgoritimo();
        int selecao = 0; // definimos para o metodo roleta
        ISelectionMethod metodoDeSelecao = (selecao == 0) ? (ISelectionMethod)new RouletteWheelSelection() :
            (selecao == 1) ? (ISelectionMethod)new EliteSelection() :
                (ISelectionMethod)new RankSelection();

        AvaliadorDeRainhas avaliador = new AvaliadorDeRainhas();
        Population populacao = new Population(nPopulacao, new ShortArrayChromosome(nRainhas, nRainhas - 1), avaliador, metodoDeSelecao);
        populacao.CrossoverRate = crossoverRate;
        populacao.MutationRate = mutationRate;


        int iteracao = 0;
        int pararEm = nParada;
        while (iteracao < nGeracoes)
        {
            populacao.RunEpoch();

            if (nParada > 0 && iteracao == pararEm)
            {
                atualizaDadosPara(iteracao, populacao);

                pararEm += nParada;
            }
            if (populacao.BestChromosome.Fitness == nRainhas)
                break;
            iteracao++;
        }

        atualizaDadosPara(iteracao,populacao);
    }

    private void atualizaDadosPara(int iteracao,Population populacao)
    {
        log = "Geração: " + iteracao +
            "\n Método de Seleção : " + populacao.SelectionMethod +
                "\n Avaliação Média: " + populacao.FitnessAvg +
                "\n Melhor Avaliação : " + populacao.FitnessMax +
                "\n Melhor indivíduo: " + populacao.BestChromosome.ToString();
        print (log);
    }

    private void configuraAlgoritimo(){
        try
        {
            nPopulacao = Math.Max(10, Math.Min(100, int.Parse(populationSizeBox)));
        }
        catch
        {
            nPopulacao = 8;
        }
        try
        {
            nGeracoes = Math.Max(0, int.Parse(iterationsBox));
        }
        catch
        {
            nGeracoes = 100;
        }
        try
        {
            nRainhas = Math.Max(4, int.Parse(nRainhasBox));
        }
        catch
        {
            nRainhas = 8;
        }
        try
        {
            crossoverRate = Math.Max(0.0, int.Parse(crossoverRateBox));
        }
        catch
        {
            crossoverRate = 0.75;
        }
        try
        {
            mutationRate = Math.Max(0.0, int.Parse(motacaoRateBox));
        }
        catch
        {
            mutationRate = 0.01;
        }
        try
        {
            nParada = Math.Max(0, int.Parse(paradaBox));
        }
        catch
        {
            nParada = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems that your projects misses a reference to `AForge` library. Can you find it in References folder in your `ProjectName.CSharp` folder? There is also possibility that this library is not supported for Unity3D projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated the problem that occured in your case.
You're missing `AForge.dll` file in your project's `\Assets` folder.

DLL you are looking for should be located in `AForge.NET Framework-x.x.x-(libs only)\Release` folder that you probably have downloaded zipped from AForge.NET site.

If you still struggle to find it, consider redownloading whole package from choosing `[ Download Libraries Only ]`:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html

I've also fixed some issues you had there. You don't need to cast `int` value with `int.Parse()` if it is declared as int already.
Just do `Math.Max(x, y)` etc with functions you are using.
Also you are not using anything from `AForge.Math` namespace. If that was intentional, consider removing `using AForge.Math;` as it's unused.